# Magento 2 - Admin module - how to SELECT data from database to display in Admin page

Tags: magento2, database, admin, event-observer, adminhtml

I'm building out an Admin module that's intended to SELECT data from a specific table in magento database and display that data on page, it's a custom table called "commission_sales".  At this point I just want to SELECT * (all data) from table and display on page.

The following code does work, i've tested on the **order success page** and data does pull through.  I just can't seem to do the same for the admin page:

**Note: I've also tried to trigger this code in events.xml with no luck**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 *  
 */
namespace MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class commission_data implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('commission_sales');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableName;
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); 
        echo '<pre> Data currently saved to commission_sales table</pre><pre>'; echo ($result); echo '</pre>';      
    }
}  
?>
```

How would you incorporate the above SELECT request and then display that data in an admin page/module?

Current files for the admin module so far:

```
   MyCompany
    `-- ExampleAdminNewPage
        |
        |-- Controller
        |   |-- Adminhtml
        |       |-- HelloWorld
        |           `-- Index.php
        |-- etc
        |   |-- adminhtml
        |   |   |-- menu.xml
        |   |   `-- routes.xml
        |   |   `-- events.xml
        |   `-- module.xml
        |-- view
        |   |-- adminhtml
        |       |-- layout
        |       |    `-- exampleadminnewpage_helloworld_index.xml
        |       `-- templates
        |           `-- helloworld.phtml
        |-- composer.json
        `-- registration.php
```

Appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are using observer for any admin event. You can add below code in your observer to check that your observer file is being called or not.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
  $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
  $logger->addWriter($writer);
  $logger->info(print_r($result,1));   
}
```

It will create new log file named 'test.log' and with fetched data print in it.

Comment: Thank you for this info, didn't think to use zend logging.  I"ll follow up with my findings.